# Cypress returns "browserslist" error in Create React App?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cypress, create-react-app

I've got a very simple Create React App that I am trying to implement Cypress with. I initially had a [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72035618/cypress-returns-webpack-compilation-error-for-scss-file-in-create-react-app/72036118#72036118) but related error that I was able to overcome. I'm not entirely sure why I would be given this type of error considering I do have the default "browserslist" key in my package.json file.

*package.json*

```json
{
  "name": "cypress_test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.13.1",
    "npm": "8.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "cypress": "cypress open",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cypress/react": "^5.12.4",
    "@cypress/webpack-dev-server": "^1.8.4",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.6.3",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.6.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "browserslist": "^4.6.3",
    "cypress": "^9.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.11.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "extends": [
        "plugin:cypress/recommended"
      ],
      "files": [
        "cypress/**/*.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "resolutions": {
    "@mui/styled-engine": "npm:@mui/styled-engine-sc@latest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/cypress/"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I initially installed CRA, it used the latest version of React 18, but apparently Cypress doesn't have support for 18 yet so I downgraded React to 17. I'm wondering if there are some sort of package mismatches that I'm unaware of and aren't receiving specific errors for. As a note though, the app runs fine in the browser. Here are the other related files:

*/cypress/plugins/index.js:*

```js
const findWebpack = require('find-webpack')
const webpackPreprocessor = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor');
const injectDevServer = require('@cypress/react/plugins/react-scripts');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  const webpackOptions = findWebpack.getWebpackOptions();

  if (!webpackOptions) {
    throw new Error('Could not find Webpack in this project');
  }

  const cleanOptions = { reactScripts: true };

  findWebpack.cleanForCypress(cleanOptions, webpackOptions);

  const options = {
    webpackOptions,
    watchOptions: {},
  };

  on('file:preprocessor', webpackPreprocessor(options));
  injectDevServer(on, config);
  return config;
};
```

*App.spec.js:*

```js
import React from 'react';
import data from '../fixtures/data.json';
import App from '../../src/App.jsx';

describe('Test search functionality', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.mount(<App />);
  });

  it('renders new fact when search is performed', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3001')
    // Type in search input
    cy.get('input').type('Test');

    // Click on search button
    cy.get('.submit-btn').click();

    // Intercept the request and return the mock data
    cy
      .intercept({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT}/jokes/search?query=Test`
      }, {
        fixture: data.result[1]
      })
      .as('fetchFact');

    // cy.wait(['@fetchFact']);

    cy.get('p.copy').should('contain', data.result[1].value);
  })
});
```

*cypress.json:*

```json
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3001",
  "videos": false,
  "component": {
    "testFiles": "**/*.cy.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "componentFolder": "src"
  }
}
```

*Cypress error:*

```
Error: No browserslist config found to handle the 'browserslist' target.
See https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries for possible ways to provide a config.
The recommended way is to add a 'browserslist' key to your package.json and list supported browsers (resp. node.js versions).
You can also more options via the 'target' option: 'browserslist' / 'browserslist:env' / 'browserslist:query' / 'browserslist:path-to-config' / 'browserslist:path-to-config:env'
    at TARGETS.web (/Users/jimmiejackson/Documents/repositories/cypress_test/node_modules/webpack/lib/config/target.js:93:11)
    at getTargetProperties (/Users/jimmiejackson/Documents/repositories/cypress_test/node_modules/webpack/lib/config/target.js:296:19)
    at /Users/jimmiejackson/Documents/repositories/cypress_test/node_modules/webpack/lib/config/target.js:342:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at getTargetsProperties (/Users/jimmiejackson/Documents/repositories/cypress_test/node_modules/webpack/lib/config/target.js:342:11)
    at applyWebpackOptionsDefaults (/Users/jimmiejackson/Documents/repositories/cypress_test/node_modules/webpack/lib/config/defaults.js:142:6)
    at createCompiler (/Users/jimmiejackson/Documents/repositories/cypress_test/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:77:2)
    at create (/Users/jimmiejackson/Documents/repositories/cypress_test/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:134:16)
    at webpack (/Users/jimmiejackson/Documents/repositories/cypress_test/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:158:32)
    at f (/Users/jimmiejackson/Documents/repositories/cypress_test/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js:63:16)
    at Object.handler (/Users/jimmiejackson/Documents/repositories/cypress_test/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor/dist/index.js:148:24)
    at invoke (/Users/jimmiejackson/Library/Caches/Cypress/9.6.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_plugins.js:22:16)
    at /Users/jimmiejackson/Library/Caches/Cypress/9.6.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/util.js:45:14
    at tryCatcher (/Users/jimmiejackson/Library/Caches/Cypress/9.6.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/Users/jimmiejackson/Library/Caches/Cypress/9.6.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:39:29)
    at Object.wrapChildPromise (/Users/jimmiejackson/Library/Caches/Cypress/9.6.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/util.js:44:23)
    at Object.wrap (/Users/jimmiejackson/Library/Caches/Cypress/9.6.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/child/preprocessor.js:28:8)
    at execute (/Users/jimmiejackson/Library/Caches/Cypress/9.6.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_plugins.js:123:27)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/jimmiejackson/Library/Caches/Cypress/9.6.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_plugins.js:213:5)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/jimmiejackson/Library/Caches/Cypress/9.6.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/util.js:19:22)
    at process.emit (node:events:390:28)
```

Comment: Do you get the same error, if you try with `"browserslist": [">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all"]`?

Comment: @MarioVarchmin you know, I ended up copying it all over to a new NextJS project and it worked fine, so I'm convinced that there were some version mismatches of libraries going on. From what I understand, CRA isn't in a good place these days and NextJS is usually recommended over CRA anyways.

Answer (score 0):

changing the browserlist in the package.json fixed the problems I was having

````
"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.4"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%",
    "not dead"
  ]```
````